# Bootstrap container without row vs with row has only one column with width is 100%

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In some cases, the container has only 1 row and the row has only 1 column - 100% width. There are 3 use cases:

- **Use Case 1**

  ```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
                <div> Child </div>
           </div>
       </div>
  </div>
  ```
- **Use Case 2 ( Use row only)** - I have seen this in Bootstrap Examples templates

  ```
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">              
          <div> Child </div>               
       </div>
  </div>
  ```
- **Use Case 3 ( No row)**

  ```
  <div class="container">
      <div> Child </div>               
  </div>
  ```

The Use Case 2 seems invalid to me because no column used inside the row div. Should I ever use The use case 3 instead of the Use case 1? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example 1 vs Example 3 - Totally depends on you requirement.

For only 1 column, both example 1 and 3 makes sense.

But, you can go with example 1 just in case you'll need to place a new element in future then there's no need to add divs with row and col again. (from my experience)

As you suggested, example 2 is of no use since it actually touches the left edge of the screen and it certainly doesn't look good.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. I will see if there is another answer before approve your answer.

Comment: Your question makes sense too, it is actually something to understand before starting bootstrap grid. Upvoted :)